Store a crsf token on a cookie
Well, im learning about csrf protection for my angular - spring boot app.
Now, i've been reading about this on angular documentation and it says

HttpClient supports a common mechanism used to prevent XSRF attacks. When performing HTTP requests, an interceptor reads a token from a cookie, by default XSRF-TOKEN, and sets it as an HTTP header, X-XSRF-TOKEN. Because only code that runs on your domain could read the cookie, the backend can be certain that the HTTP request came from your client application and not an attacker.

link: HTTP client - Security: Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF) protection
I means that csrf is on a cookie HttpOnly false, and my angular interceptor pull my csrf token that is on a cookie and creates a extra header called "X-XSRF-TOKEN" and it's send with each request.
but, if i have csrf token on a cookie httpfalse OWASP says NO bro

a CSRF token should not be transmitted in a cookie for synchronized patterns. A CSRF token must not be leaked in the server logs or in the URL

Link Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention Cheat Sheet
This seems to contradict the approach described in Angular's documentation. Additionally, Spring Boot's documentation indicates:

In order to obtain the CSRF token, you can configure Spring Security to store the expected CSRF token in a cookie. By storing the expected token in a cookie, JavaScript frameworks such as Angular can automatically include the actual CSRF token as an HTTP request header.

Link: Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
I'm i missing something ?
How does this method effectively protect my application from CSRF attacks, considering the token is stored in a cookie with HttpOnly: false?
Finally, is this a good way to secure my SPA of a csrf attack, or should i consider another way to protect my app??
Thanks for your time.

If you use an Authorization header instead of cookies you don't have to worry about this at all. Consider doing that instead

thanks but the app is already done with session cookies and i'm trying to understant this topic

Another (more simple) method to secure your backend against CSRF is to require a custom-header for any state-changing request.  (only JS could set the custom header, and that will always be pre-flighted so as long as you haven't loosened CORS rules by setting CORS headers you'll be good.  Keep everything same-site/domain.)  It can be set to anything.  If your state-changing requests already require authentication/authorization via a custom header, you are likewise already protected.

remember that this is only anti-CSRF.  You always need to mitigate against XSS, too.  If an XSS attack goes through, the attacker can do all sorts of things... including prompting the user for their login credentials and sending them somewhere else.

"a CSRF token should not be transmitted in a cookie for synchronized patterns.":  this means your backend shouldn't read the cookie... it needs to require that it be read from the custom-header.  Or from the form data/json, but Angular's method reads the same-site cookie and sets the header for all requests.  "A CSRF token must not be leaked in the server logs or in the URL":  this means, don't send it in a GET request.  (GETs are often logged... cookies are not)  Ex: my_state_changing_endpoint?anti-csrf=seoJOEWIF9832jhlf...

also if you generate these tokens (non-httponly cookie) per request/response, this will have the added benefit of helping to mitigate CRIIME/BREACH attacks... just add them to every response regardless of method of request... you don't need to send or use them at all... the fact that the server response is different every time helps here.
